# How to add suggest plugin to theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes

Some templates where I installed, it showing some plugins suggest to install for support it.

How to can I suggest for user some plugins to support my theme?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation

Comment: @SamuelElh is working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TGM Plugin Activation](https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation) is the most popular PHP library among WordPress theme developers to  allows them to easily require or recommend plugins for your WordPress themes (and plugins).

It allows your users to install, update and even automatically activate plugins in singular or bulk fashion using native WordPress classes, functions and interfaces

Comment: Are there any limitations to the recommended number of plugins with WordPress.org theme?

Comment: No. There is no limit.